# AWS API with additional parameter to Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I would like to add an additional argument to my AWS API to be passed to AWS Lambda in java, so that my generic Lambda can know which operation to invoke.

Is mapping template the only way to do this or is there any other way?

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear to me, but would using the event object work? If you got to Lambada, Actions > Configure Test Event, you can build a JSON-format event of key/value pairs that you can access in the Lambda like so: event["YourParameter"]

Comment: Apologies if the question was not clear. Configure test event would not work coz that essentially becomes part of the request from calling party. My Lambda's are exposed as AWS Gateway API's. I do not want to add the argument in the request body but intercept it at the AWS API stage and then add the new argument to be passed to the Lambda.

Comment: I think I have this figured out, mapping templates look like the way to go. Thanks All.